# Wordpress latest posts can't grab current URL

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I snagged the following code to grab the current page URL...

```
                <?php
                function curPageURL() {
                 $pageURL = 'http';
                 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
                 $pageURL .= "://";
                 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
                  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                 } else {
                  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                 }
                 return $pageURL;
                }
            ?>
```

This way I can put the current page URL into a Facebook like button for my template...

```
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

This works fine on all pages of my Wordpress site but I get an error on my latest posts pages. I can't make more than one post without getting this error...

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare curpageurl() (previously declared in /home4/whimint/public_html/whetink.co/wp-content/themes/kingdom/content.php:81) in /home4/whimint/public_html/whetink.co/wp-content/themes/kingdom/content.php on line 90

Any thoughts? Let me know if you need more details, I am new to Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare curpageurl() (previously declared in /home4/whimint/public_html/whetink.co/wp-content/themes/kingdom/content.php:81) in /home4/whimint/public_html/whetink.co/wp-content/themes/kingdom/content.php on line 90

this error says, that your function is twice in your file (content.php). once in line 81, once in line 90.

your code shows the function in camel case, the error in lowercase. php functions are case insensitive. 
did you try to have multiple functions with the same (case insensitive) name?

Comment: It's only in my content.php once. When I have just one post on my Wordpress blog it works fine, but when I have 2 or more posts I get this error. It seems like it's duplicating for each post

Answer (score 0):

Move the function to the functions.php file so it is only declared once. You can also wrap it in this to prevent it being declared twice.

```
if(!function_exists("curPageURL")){
function curPageURL() {
   $pageURL = 'http';
   if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";
   if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
   } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
   }
    return $pageURL;
}
}
```